# Can parameter of function in react.useCallback be in dependent list?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When using useCallback hook, why the the parameter of the function cannot be the dependency in the dependency list? If I use the parameter in the list, it gives me error like below.

```
const memoizedCallback = useCallback(
  (c) => {
    doSomething();
  },
  [c],
);
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish? The array is there to decide when to break the memoization; Ie, when to create a new function. Are you wanting it to be that when they call the callback with some parameter, a new function is created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify those dependencies to useCallback dependency array which are defined in the enclosing closure. The parameter to function within the useCallback aren't available outside of the function and hence cannot be specified in the dependency array.

Also you need not specify it in dependency array since whenever the function is called if will receive a new parameter without the need for function to be recreated which is what the dependency array is for.

Answer (score -2):

```
const memoizedCallback = (c) => {
     const output = useCallback(
      (c) => {
        doSomethingLongProcessing();
      },
      [c],
    );
   return output(c);
}
```